# Trouble installing tar.gz

Tags: r

I am a novice R user, trying to access a dataset for my research. The dataset is located here: https://zenodo.org/record/17500#.V7b8pFsrJQL

When I try to install COMPASSDataPackage_1.0.0.tar.gz I get the following errors:

```
> install.packages("/Users/dmb74/Documents/R/Temp/RGLab-COMPASSDataPackage-bc24b5a/COMPASSDataPackage_1.0.0.tar.gz", repos = NULL)
* installing *source* package 'COMPASSDataPackage' ...
** R
** data
** preparing package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  there is no package called 'COMPASS'
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'COMPASSDataPackage'
* removing 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.2.2/library/COMPASSDataPackage'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.2/bin/i386/R" CMD INSTALL -l        
"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.2\library" "/Users/dmb74/Documents/R/Temp/RGLab-    
   COMPASSDataPackage-bc24b5a/COMPASSDataPackage_1.0.0.tar.gz"' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘/Users/dmb74/Documents/R/Temp/RGLab-    
  COMPASSDataPackage-bc24b5a/COMPASSDataPackage_1.0.0.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Here is the sesion info:

```
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.2.2
```

Comment: You need to tell R to use a local file, not the default repor. To do this, in the `install.packages` function include the argument `repo = NULL`

Comment: Sorry, that is the usual issue. I think it is because the dependent, `COMPASS` package isn't installed.

Comment: That was it NJBurgo, thanks! I installed COMPASS and now the package is loading in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NJBurgo pointed out that I needed to install the COMPASS package